# In a template, is it possible to get the content of a block by the block ID?

Tags: views, theming, blocks

I am working with some view templates in Drupal 8, and I have the block ID of another view block I want to pull into the template. Is it possible to use the block ID to get the content of a block in a template?

If this is not possible in Twig, how could I achieve this otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Yes take a look at this module :

> Twig Blocks

https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_blocks

After module install just call the block like this in the template :

```
{{ render_block('machine_name_of_your_block') }}
```

Or in a hook :

```
function hook_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{

    $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('id_block');

    $variables['myBlock'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getViewBuilder('block')
        ->view($block);

}
```

Then in your twig template :

```
  {{ myBlock }}
```

Comment: The greater issue is here is that I am using a plugin that lets the user choose whatever views block they want so I won't know what the machine name of the block is.

Comment: i have update my answer

Comment: I would need to pass the block id into
    $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load(1234); ?

Comment: yes you need to pass the block id into Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load()

Answer (score 0):

Yes by using [twig tweaks](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak). See the [cheat sheet](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#drupal-block) for blocks and more.

> The greater issue is here is that I am using a plugin that lets the user choose whatever views block they want so I won't know what the machine name of the block is

Pass the ID in as a variable and use

```
{# Print block using default configuration. #}
{{ drupal_block( block_id ) }}
```